# Store image in database in server

Tags: java, mysql, sqldatatypes

Other than store the byte array, URL and file path of image, is there any way to store the image in database in the server.?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a good and valid question.

Comment: store is as a BLOB of some type

Answer (score 0):

If the image will be delivered to HTML, it is probably better to

- store the image as a file
- reference it via `<img src=url-path-to-file>`
- and store only the url (or part of it) in the table.

Yes, you could store it in a column of datatype `BLOB`, but then what will you do with it?  Write it to a file?  Encode it in base64 for a tricky form of `<img>`?